# How to find records in a group by where only 1 field is different

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 fields (empno,jobcode,abscode,unittype) and want to find all the records when only the unittype is different

Comment: I think its similar to  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473239/sql-query-to-get-group-by-and-distinct-values-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select empno,jobcode,abscode,Count(unittype) 
from Tab
Group by empno,jobcode,abscode
Having Count(unittype)>1
```

Comment: @user1345246 could you define duplicates

Comment: 2 duplicate recs in DB, 30775,NHR,H are coming out in the query

Comment: `Group by empno,jobcode,abscode` can not have duplicates in the columns empno,jobcode,abscode. Either there is a difference, or I did not understand your request. In the second case you should refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

Almost had it:

```
Select empno,jobcode,abscode,Count(Distinct unittype) 
from Tab
Group by empno,jobcode,abscode
Having Count(Distinct unittype)>1
```